# How can I reboot a Windows XP64 Machine in a Python Script?

Tags: python, windows

How can I reboot a Windows XP64 Machine in a Python Script?  This machine does not have the "shutdown" or "restart" executables available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

found it

win32api.InitiateSystemShutdown("localhost", "Maintenance Reboot", 60, 1, 1)

Answer (score 2):

You can use win32api module and call WinApi functions.
[Recipe at code.activestate.com](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/360649/)